# Get Level Information of non-revit model - NWC

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I could not use the extension of level information(Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension) directly and I tried to use a workaround which is described below link.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc

However, it did not work for me. I tried it as in the below code. But, when i tried to print length of the dbIds it returns zero. So, I could not fill the levels. What can be the problem and why the layer searching is not worked?

```
            async function findLevels(model) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    viewer.model.search(
                        'Layer',
                        (dbIds) => {
                            const levels = [];
                            const tree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
                            console.log('Db Ids: ' + dbIds.length);
                            for( let i=0; i&lt;dbIds.length; i++ ) {
                                const dbId = dbIds[i];
                                const name = tree.getNodeName( dbId );


                                if( name.includes( '&lt;No level&gt;' ) ) continue;

                                levelsGeo.push({
                                    guid: dbId,
                                    name,
                                    dbId,
                                    extension: {
                                        buildingStory: true,
                                        structure: false,
                                        computationHeight: 0,
                                        groundPlane: false,
                                        hasAssociatedViewPlans: false,
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            resolve(levelsGeo);
                        },
                        reject,
                        ['Icon']
                    );
                });
            }
```

Comment: May I know which source model this NWC comes from?  In the blog, my colleague Eason indicates: These tricks are working only for NWC exported from Revit. More specifically, the NWC must be exported from an RVT model.

Comment: if it is from Revit, the second I would check if  there if Layer property with the item in this model?

Comment: it is Revit model, but I think I need to check if there is layer property as you mentioned